# configure pre html tag for parsley validation

Tags: javascript, html, parsley.js

I cannot validate content in pre html tag using parsley validation (javascript).

While it works fine for other tags (input, textarea) it does not work with pre. The tag is set to have maxlength = 5, then it is initialized, but when I write to it and exceed the restriction nothing happens.

```
<textarea id="some id" data-parsley="true" data-parsley-maxlength="5" 
data-parsley-trigger="keyup" data-parsley-maxlength-message="too many signs" />

<pre contenteditable="true" id="pre_id" style="width:270px"
             data-parsley="true"
             data-parsley-maxlength="5"
             data-parsley-trigger="keyup"
             data-parsley-maxlength-message="Too many signs"
             class="pre-edit">
</pre>
```

and in javascript:

```
initializeAllParsleyFields();
```

which truly initializes all fields containing data-parsley-true

Comment: Did you get it tp work?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to [modify the `inputs` configuration](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#psly-usage-form) to include the `pre` tag or something.